# How to write a multi-protocol handler on a single port using Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, binary, ascii, netty

I'm a newbie on Netty, and I'm wondering how to read/handle incoming TCP data when the TCP client sometimes sends variable length binary records (hex) and sometimes sends variable length ASCII records, none of which are delimited by carriage return or line feed.

The TCP client is sending a stream of bytes as follows:

1. A binary stream of bytes that begins with '$' but has a varying number of bytes and not terminated by any character, and
2. An ASCII stream of bytes that begins with '(' and ends with ')' but has a varying number of bytes and not terminated by any character

Both sets of records arrive on the same port.

How would I need to code my Netty-based TCP server to handle/read both?

Thanks in advance.

Kunal

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [port unification example](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/portunification/package-summary.html). It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't mix everything together '$' is a Char, it can be represented by one single Byte in most encoding but this is hardly the case for a common char (in UTF-8, char a variable length encoded and can use 1, 2 or 3 Bytes).

It depends the length of your stream.

1) The easiest solution, if it can **fit inside the memory** of your sender, is to **use a frame with a two fields header**:

- one Byte for the type (byte or String)
- 2 Bytes (using an unsigned Int16 for instance) for the length of the frame the (number of Bytes of data).

Than, you could use a FrameDecoder to receive and decode the whole frame.

2) If your stream is huge and **cannot fit inside the memory**, you have two solutions:

- **Split your stream into frames** (with a little overhead because of the header of each frame)
- Use the **Channel.close()** event to notify the **EndOfStream** (which is easier but can cause some latency issues if you need to create a new connection and do some handshaking again and again...

In every case Netty prodives some **StringEncoder** and **StringDecoder** for streaming Strings. And also some **FrameDecoder** and **FrameEncoder** with all kinds of usefull headers.